# Merge date, time and datetime tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms, retag-request

While editing/tagging a question, I noticed that the [datetime](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datetime) tag has this info:

> for questions specific to data types that contain both date and time parts.

which seems wrong to me. Seeing a "datetime" tag, I would assume the question has to do with "date **or** time", not "date and time".

So I suggest we merge the 3 tags. I don't think we need 3 separate tags, one for each type, for several reasons:

- DBMS have sections in their documentation about *"Date/Time types"* and *"Date/Time functions and operators"*.
- The two parts (date and time) are related as they exist as separate types and parts of combined types (datetime, timestamp).
- Questions about a specific type (eg. question specifically about `date` type are rare and I can't see how tagging with date will be more help than tagging with datetime.
- Some DBMS (call me Oracle) have no pure `date` type and they call the `datetime` type `date`. Which tag should Oracle users use?
  Or have a tag for each type and dbms: [oracle-date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle-date), [sql-server-date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-date), [sql-server-datetime](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-datetime), etc? (No, I wouldn't like that)

[datetime](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datetime) has 175 questions, [date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) has 98 and [time](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) has 45
(and some of them are common, 15 for example are tagged with both date and datetime).

**Are the three tags similar enough to be merged?**

Or is there any important difference between them from a [tagging perspective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32041/194636)?

If you think the tags are different, please add your reasoning to the '**No**' CW answer below.

If you agree the tags should be merged, vote '**Yes**'.

---

Additional discussion regarding [timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timestamp) and tags about non-standard non-standard types like [datetime2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datetime2)

- Not sure about [timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timestamp), and whether it should be merged or not (shall we have a separate meta question?)
- [datetime2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datetime2) is very rare (only 2 questions) and vendor specific, so it could be independently merged into [datetime](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datetime) or not. It doesn't matter much.

Comment: Cool, but I'm still unclear how you think [tag:datetime] should be used (its guidance). Should the merge target be [tag:datetime] or [tag:date-time]? Also, how do you feel about [tag:timestamp] and [tag:datetime2] continuing separately? Feel free to ignore the last part if it is simply out of scope.

Comment: I don't know, Paul already mentioned `datetime2` but more specifically I would feel weird asking a question about the `date` data type specifically and having to use the `datetime` tag.

Comment: I have the opposite feeling but not very strong views, that's why I posted on meta. About datetime2, there are exactly 2 questions tagged with it. Isn't the datetime tag enough to handle those questions, too?

Answer (score 6):

**No**, the 3 tags [date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date), [time](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) and [datetime](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datetime) **should remain separate**.

Comment: They're discrete types under the hood, and at least in PostgreSQL often functions accept one type and not the other. For instance, I just recently asked [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/158907/2639) which has to do with time to the exclusion of date internal and external. That said, I don't much care about this. So while I am voting to keep them seperate, I feel less passionately about this then other things we've disagreed upon. I prefer tags to be more meaningful, even if it takes more skill to use them properly.

Comment: @Evan I'm not talking about the types but about the tags. I've added some explanation in the question why I think we only need one tag, for the 3+ different types.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, [date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) and [time](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) **should be synonyms** of [datetime](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/datetime) and **merged**.